# Drupal 7 basic page with a dynamic block with arguments

Tags: drupal-7

Can anyone guide me to a route to take as far as making a basic page in drupal 7 and then having that page load a block with images inside based on URL path.

So I have a content type that is for 1 type of pages and another content type for another type of page. Each content type has 30 pages. I don't want to create 30 pages for 1 page that will have the same content over and over but with a different logo.

http://www.example.com/contenttype1name/%/staticname

I need to make the menu have an argument passed and then based on what is passed go get the correct image.

Sorry if this is confusing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used contextual filters on views and nodesymlinks along with panels that was already installed. 
Modules Used:
Views
Nodesymlinks
Panels

Step 1: admin > Modules > Add Modules/Enable.
Enable Nodesymlinks
Enable Panels and panelizer

Step 2: admin > Structure > Views > Add View.
Make view, name it and check block not page (I used Fields).

Step 3: admin > Structure > Views > your view.
Add filtered Criteria - Content type = your type.
Content should be Published only.
Add contextual filter: title.
Configure contextual filter: Content: Title.
Provide default value. Select Raw Value from URL.
Path component select 2. You can add it where you want in the URL.
Use path alias and check it.
Under More you need to check this box: Transform spaces to dashes in URL.
Check it in Views and save.

Step 4: admin > Content > Add Page.
Add a basic page.
On the bottom of the page you will see: Provide a menu link. You want to check that box. Now you will be able to add all the menu links that you wish this page to show up on. Add links/Paths and titles. Make sure you use argument 2 in your link to be your content on the views block in step 3.

Step 5: admin > config > content > panelizer.
You want to go into this pages panelizer, could be basic or whatever your content type would be. Add your views block and save.

Step 6: 
Test it. If it doesn't work then you need to check your titles in argument 2 in the URL. Worked for me. Saved me a ton of time.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the [views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) - it allows you to easily create a view with dynamic parameters (contextual filters) that allow you to easily tackle things like this.

Comment: Tried views. Can you elaborate on this? Remember I need a menu item that is dynamic as well. The menu will be on all 30 pages. The logos would be based off the raw url? Where do I store the logos? Taxonomy?